# Visitor visa UK - two applications from different countries

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I want to apply for the UK visitor visa along with my mom however my mom lives in India and i work in USA. I have some concerns for this:

Can my mom and I apply to UK visitor visa together from two different countries?

Comment: @arora What do you mean by ‘apply together’? You both need to submit your own individual application from your country of residence. Each of you can mention in your application that you’ll be travelling to the UK to meet each other (or together, if you’re going to India and then to the UK).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, So I have not mentioned each other's reference number in the applications, can I just print the applications and submit by writing the reference numbers on the paper applications , will they accept it or I need to cancel the applications then do it all over?

Comment: So I recently got my visa approved from USA but My mother got denied twice from India. However I have submitted all the possible necessary documents in favor to her visitor visa but The refusal letter states that she does not have enough strong ties with home country and economical stability. The refusal letter talks about a bank account which does not belong to my mother or me.so probably there is a mistake which I want to challenge through judicial review.Any insight to this would be helpful.

Comment: Even if there is a mistake about the bank statement, the core refusal reason is lack of ties. You should ask a separate question, however IMHO after two refusals (presumably for the same reason) it seems unlikely a judicial review would succeed solely on the basis you describe.